# Encoding in JSF 2 + Tomcat 7

Tags: character-encoding, jsf-2, tomcat7, content-encoding

I have one form with only one single field. When I submit the form, the value of my field becomes strange. The word Extremação becomes ExtremaÃ§Ã£o.

So, I already set UTF-8 encoding in every place on my app:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<f:view contentType="text/html" encoding="UTF-8">
<h:form id="formParamSupremo"  prependId="false" acceptcharset="UTF-8">
```

I created one encoding filter too:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

And my http header is like this:

```
host = localhost:8080
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; pt-BR; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921
user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux x86_64; pt-BR; rv:1.9.2.23) Gecko/20110921        Ubuntu/10.04 (lucid) Firefox/3.6.23
accept = text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
accept-language = pt-br,pt;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
accept-encoding = gzip,deflate
accept-charset = ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
keep-alive = 115
connection = keep-alive
referer = http://localhost:8080/parametros/view/xhtml/parametrosSupremo.jsf
cookie = JSESSIONID=6DC0C1D4434FB90C3F9271D6C54DC575
content-type = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
content-length = 185
```

Comment: *"The word Extremação becomes ExtremaÃ§Ã£o."* Where exactly are you checking the value? In database? Or by `System.out.println()` in your IDE? Or in a result page in browser? Are you using JSP or Facelets?

Comment: You've edited your post, but you didn't give any feedback on my above comment. Why? Don't you want to help us to help you?

Comment: I'm checking the value in my IDE (setter method). I'm using facelets.

Comment: Which IDE? Eclipse? And how are you checking it? By `System.out.println()` or in debugger variables view? How does the value look like in webbrowser after submit?

Comment: Yes, I'm checking in eclipse debugger. When the load of page completes, the value of the field is ExtremaÃ§Ã£o.

Comment: What's the value of `Content-Type` header of the HTTP response? (you've only shown the HTTP request headers). What browser are you using? MSIE has a major problem with `acceptcharset`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem.

Finally I found this error solutions. You should create a Filter to display non ascIi characters. What an annoying bugs :(

http://dertompson.com/2007/01/29/encoding-filter-for-java-web-applications/

Comment: This one did fix my problem as well. Thanks Hung, thanks Paulo Vitor.